# how to get all lines with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on generating Wikipedia dataset from their datadump. A preview of their page source is like this:

[Wikipedia structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZgkF.png)

I want to get the entire `a` tag line, `<a href="enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz">enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz</a> 23-Sep-2020 08:25 780430373`

So that I can find the relevant lines for myself, i.e those that have `stub-meta-history` and store links of such files in a list so that I can use this list to download all relevant files.

In another situation, I would like to get links based on a specific date

This is my code:

```
soup_dump.find_all('li', {'class': 'file'}, limit = 10)[:4]
files = []

# Search through all files
for file in soup_dump.find_all('a'):
    text = file.text
    if 'stub-meta-history' in text:
        files.append(text)
```

Comment: Maybe since you `find_all` only 10 elements?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: This is the page: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/

Comment: I think you are misunterstanding your data. The dates and sizes are not part of the link (you can handle date and size with iterating over data, anyway)

Comment: another hint: I do not understand your first line. There are no list elements an you do not save this data, so this line is useless in multiple ways ;)

Answer (score 0):

The key word is `next_sibling`, with this you can reach the "next element". I don't know what do you do with the data, but here is an example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

# soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'file'}, limit = 10)[:4]
files = []

# Search through all files
for file in soup.find_all('a'):
    text = file["href"]
    if 'stub-meta-history' in text:
        files.append("{} {}".format(text, file.next_sibling.strip()))

for x in files:
    print(x)
```

Example output:

```
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history.xml.gz 21-Sep-2020 19:04         69246792624
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history.xml.gz-rss.xml 23-Sep-2020 08:28                 787
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history1.xml.gz 21-Sep-2020 00:23          2625343450
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history1.xml.gz-rss.xml 23-Sep-2020 08:27                 790
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history10.xml.gz 21-Sep-2020 08:28          2782265716
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history10.xml.gz-rss.xml 23-Sep-2020 08:27                 793
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history11.xml.gz 21-Sep-2020 08:23          2817413722
enwiki-latest-stub-meta-history11.xml.gz-rss.xml 23-Sep-2020 08:27                 793
```

Comment: Your solution works but, in case of these values, "pages-articles-multistream", an occurence would be: enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream-index12.txt-p8554860p9172788.bz2, but all such values are redacted to like this: enwiki-latest-pages-articles-multistream-.index..>

Comment: yeah, that's correct, because my code is based on your code, I changed my code to fix this (if you paste a code i try to use this as basis, and do not create something completely new)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the data later on, I think a `pandas dataframe` would do best here.

Here's my take on it:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate

response = requests.get("https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")

all_urls = [
    f"https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/{a['href']}" for a
    in soup.find_all("a") if a.text != "../"
]


def get_lines(bs4_soup):
    for index, line in enumerate(bs4_soup.getText().split('\n')[4:]):
        if line:
            _, *date_and_time, size = line.strip().split()
            yield [
                all_urls[index],
                parse_date(date_and_time),
                human_readable_size(int(size))
            ]


def human_readable_size(size, decimal_places=2):
    for unit in ['B', 'KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB']:
        if size < 1024.0 or unit == 'PiB':
            break
        size /= 1024.0
    return f"{size:.{decimal_places}f} {unit}"


def parse_date(date):
    return datetime.strptime(' '.join(date), "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")


lines = [line for line in get_lines(soup)]

columns = ["URL", "DATE AND TIME", "SIZE"]
df = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=columns)
df.to_csv("wiki_dump.csv", index=False)
print(tabulate(df[:10], showindex=False, headers=columns))
```

Output (along a `.csv` file):

```
URL                                                                                DATE AND TIME        SIZE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------------  ----------
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz            2020-09-23 08:25:00  744.28 MiB
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract.xml.gz-rss.xml    2020-09-23 08:25:00  760.00 B
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract1.xml.gz           2020-09-22 23:28:00  107.15 MiB
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract1.xml.gz-rss.xml   2020-09-23 08:24:00  763.00 B
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract10.xml.gz          2020-09-23 04:14:00  26.75 MiB
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract10.xml.gz-rss.xml  2020-09-23 08:24:00  766.00 B
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract11.xml.gz          2020-09-23 03:32:00  25.00 MiB
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract11.xml.gz-rss.xml  2020-09-23 08:24:00  766.00 B
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract12.xml.gz          2020-09-23 03:59:00  23.40 MiB
https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-abstract12.xml.gz-rss.xml  2020-09-23 08:24:00  766.00 B
and so on...
```

[image]

Comment: The solution sounds interesting, however, in case of these search keywords, "pages-articles-multistream" the final lines produce redacted lines

Comment: Also, there is an error at "return f"{size:.{decimal_places}f} {unit}""

Comment: I've fixed the issue with redacted urls. However, I'm not sure what you mean by "there's an error at `return f"{size:.{decimal_places}f} {unit}"`. Could you please give more details and a traceback?